# Demonstration of covariant derivative of a vector along another vector

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, covariance

I try to find the relation that defines the covariant derivative of a vector along another vector :

$$\nabla_{\mathbf{v}}{\mathbf{u}}=\left(v^{i}u^{j}\Gamma^{k}{}_{ij}+v^{i}{\partial u^{k} \over \partial x^{i}}\right){\mathbf{e}}_{k}\quad\quad(1)$$

Firstly, I know that $k-th$ component of covariant derivative of a vector along $(x^{i})$ coordinates is defined by :

$$(\nabla_{i}{\mathbf{u}})^{k}=\left(u^{j}\Gamma^{k}{}_{ij}+{\partial u^{k} \over \partial x^{i}}\right)$$

and also, we have : $$\text{d}\vec{e_{i}}=\Gamma^{j}{}_{ki}\text{d}x^{k}\vec{e_{j}}$$

by introducing : $$\text{d}\vec{e_{i}}=w^{j}{}_{i}\vec{e_{j}}$$

and $$w^{j}{}_{i}=\Gamma^{j}{}_{ki}\text{d}x^{k}$$

But from these basic definitions, I don't know how to find relation (1) ?

If anyone could help me, this would be fine, Regards

**UPDATE 1 :**

Thanks for your help. I have just a remark about your definition of $\nabla \vec e_i = \sum\Gamma^j_{ki} \text{d}x^k\vec e_j$. Indeed, it seeems that we could rather write the **Absolute differential** $\text{D}\vec{e_{i}}$ as :

$$\text{D}\vec{e_{i}}=(\nabla_{k} \vec{e_{i}})^{j} \text{d}x^{k} \vec{e_{j}}= ((\partial_{k}(\vec{e_{i}})^{j}+\Gamma^{j}_{kl} (\vec{e_{i}})^{l}) \text{d}x^k\vec{e_{j}}$$

Then :

$$\text{D}\vec{e_{i}}=(\partial_{k}(\vec{e_{i}})^{j}+\Gamma^{j}_{kl} \delta^{il}) \text{d}x^k\vec{e_{j}}=(\partial_{k}(\delta_{ij})+\Gamma^{j}_{ki}) \text{d}x^k\vec{e_{j}}$$

$$=\Gamma^{j}_{ki} \text{d}x^k \vec{e_{j}}$$

And we get : $$\nabla_{k} \vec{e_{i}} = \Gamma^{j}_{ki}\vec{e_{j}}$$

with : $$(\nabla_{k} \vec{e_{i}})^{j} = \Gamma^{j}_{ki}$$

**I must admit it is pretty complex and long but is it correct ?**

ps : From your notation, I could find the relation between $\nabla_{k}\vec{e_{i}}$ and $\nabla\vec{e_{i}}$ as :

$\nabla\vec{e_{i}}=\nabla_{k}\vec{e_{i}} \text{d}x^{k}$

isn't it ?

the last difference is that in Ted Shifrin's calculations, the factor $\text{d}x^{k}$ is included into definition of $\nabla$.

**UPDATE 2:**

I think it is possible to convert slightly :

$$\nabla_{\mathbf v}\mathbf u = \sum_j\left(\sum_k v^k\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^k} + \sum_{k,i}u^iv^k\Gamma^j_{ki}\right)\vec e_j$$

By factorize with $v^{k}$ in summation, Could I write this ? :

$$(\nabla_{\mathbf v}\mathbf u)^{j} = v^k\left(\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^k} + u^i\Gamma^j_{ki}\right)= v^{k} (\nabla_{k}\vec{u})^{j}=(v^{k}\,\nabla_{k}\vec{u})^{j}$$

knowing $\vec{v}=v^{k}\vec{e_{k}}$.

From a general point of view, is this rule valid (as a function of subscript on $\nabla_{k}$):

$$(\nabla_{\mathbf v}\mathbf u)^{j}=(v^{i}\,\nabla_{i}\mathbf u)^{j}$$

?? If you had a wiki link or others to prove this property, let me know it, I will be satisfied.

Last point, is there a way **to grasp the difference between a covariant derivative as respect of a basis vector** (which models the transport along a curvilinear coordinate) **and a covariant derivative as respect of a vector or vector field** (I don't if this works for both vector and field vector) ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it should be $\nabla \vec e_i = \sum\Gamma^j_{ki} dx^k\vec e_j$. (Having $u^k$ as coordinates and also as coefficients of your vector field will *not* do.) You're writing the vector field $\mathbf u = \sum u^i\vec e_i$, and you differentiate using the product rule, obtaining
\begin{align*}
\nabla\mathbf u &= \nabla \big(\sum_i u^i\vec e_i\big) = \sum_{k,i}\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x^k}dx^k\vec e_i + \sum_i u^i\sum_{k,j}\Gamma^j_{ki} dx^k \vec e_j \\
&= \sum_j\big(\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^k}dx^k + \sum_{k,i} u^i\Gamma^j_{ki} dx^k \big)\vec e_j.
\end{align*}
Now evaluate on the tangent vector $\mathbf v = \sum v^k\vec e_k$ to obtain
$$\nabla_{\mathbf v}\mathbf u = \sum_j\left(\sum_k v^k\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^k} + \sum_{k,i}u^iv^k\Gamma^j_{ki}\right)\vec e_j,$$
as desired. (At this point, you can relabel the indices to get your original formula.)

Comment: -@Ted Shifrin . Thanks, however could you take a look at my **UPDATE 1** to know if my demonstration is correct. This demo is a little tricky but I would like your advice. Regards

Comment: In fact, it's included in yours as well. You didn't provide full context or definitions of your symbols. Your equation $d\vec e_i = \dots$ should have been $\nabla\vec e_i$, as I pointed out. There's no difference between $D$ and $\nabla$ as we're using it, except that you seem to want to write $\nabla_k$ for $\nabla_{\partial/\partial x^k} = D_{\partial/\partial x^k}$.

Comment: -@Ted Shifrin. a last point, I would like to know if the relation into my **UPDATE 2** is correct, i.e : $(\nabla_{\mathbf v}\mathbf u)^{j}=v^{i}\,(\nabla_{i}\mathbf u)^{j}$ and if yes, is there a demonstration ? thanks

Comment: Yes, that's right. It follows immediately from my formula, but intuitively you should think of $\nabla_{\mathbf v}$ as a directional derivative in the $\mathbf v$ direction, and, as such, it's linear in $\mathbf v$. You're just writing $\mathbf v = \sum v^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and using linearity. To answer your last question: If you want to think in terms of differentiating along a coordinate curve, you can similarly think about differentiating along the integral curve (or flow line) of your vector field $\mathbf v$.

Comment: Can $\nabla_{\mathbf v}\mathbf u$  be assimilated  to the Lie derivative of $\mathbf{u}$ vector (field ?) along $\mathbf{v}$  vector ?

Comment: Lie derivative doesn't use any covariant derivative — it depends just on the differentiable structure of the manifold. You differentiate along the flow of the vector field $\mathbf v$. There is an analogous interpretation of the covariant derivative, considering the parallel translation of $\mathbf u$ along the flow.

Comment: -@Ted Shifrin. However, from this link : https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-Lie-derivative-and-covariant-derivative-How-do-you-interpret-these-geometrically , it is defined $\mathscr{L}_{\mathbf{v}}\xi^{\alpha} = v^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}\xi^{\alpha}$, why do you say that we don't use covariant derivative with Lie derivative ? Regards

Comment: It's wrong. Don't believe everything you read on the web. What *is* correct, is that for the Levi-Civita connection we have $\nabla_XY - \nabla_YX = [X,Y]=\mathscr L_X Y$.

Comment: -@Ted Shifrin : ok so in the formula $\nabla_XY - \nabla_YX = [X,Y]=\mathscr L_X Y$,   $\nabla_X Y$ represents the covariant derivative of vector fied $Y$ along $X$ vector (or as general tensor fields? )? if no, what does $\nabla_X Y$ represent ? thanks

Comment: Yes, it's the same notation you were using. I just didn't want to type all those mathbf's.

Comment: -@Ted Shifrin . Thanks a lot ! a last question (I don't want to bore you) : into expression, $\nabla_X Y$,      $X$ can also represent from a general point of view, a field tensor ? like $Y$ by the way ?

Comment: No, you have to differentiate in the direction of a vector field, so $X$ is always a vector field. You can differentiate arbitrary tensor fields, but the formula I typed there holds *only* for a torsion-free connection on the tangent bundle, i.e., for vector fields only.